# DNA to 2 bit binary representation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dna-sequence

I want to convert a given DNA sequence into its corresponding 2 bit binary sequence obeying the following rule: `A = 00`, `C = 01`, `T = 10`, `G = 11`. I have written the following code.

```
str = 'ATTCGA';
[~,idx]= ismember(upper(str),'ATCG');
C= {'00', '10', '01', '11'};
z= [c{idx}]-'0';
R = 0.992;
theta = (2*pi)/3;
b = [1 0 -1];
a = [1 -2*R*cos(theta) R^2];
u = filter(b,a,z);
Y = abs(u).^2; 
plot(Y/max(Y)); 
axis([0 8000 0 1.05]);
```

But the problem is the code is generating a single bit per cell whereas I need 2 bits per cell:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What exactly do you want the result in `z` to be?

Comment: z will be sequence of binary numbers to be passed through a digital filter.

Comment: But how do you want to **represent** those binary numbers? Currently `z` in your example gets the value `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`. Please edit the question to show **literally** what you want it to be instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're well underway, you're just indexing/concatenating in the wrong way:

```
str     = 'ATTCGA';
[~,idx] = ismember(upper(str),'ATCG');
dna_map = {'00', '10', '01', '11'};

% Index with parentheses instead of braces, and don't concatenate
dna_bin = dna_map(idx)
```

this will give you the corresponding cell-array:

```
dna_bin = 
    '00'    '10'    '10'    '01'    '11'    '00'
```

Not sure what you want to do with the remaining steps, though...

Comment: The output of the previous code is in cell format. I want to apply fitter to the converted sequence. Input of 'filter' in matlab  only takes single or double. That is why I have used z= [c{idx}]-'0'' to convert a cell into double.

Comment: @Subhajit ...well, then it's not clear to me what you want to accomplish. Why not map to `0`-`3`, use that in `filter`, and convert back to binary when and where needed?